# Can't set filter in pivot table - error 424

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a file with a pivot table. I need to select some filter with VBA, so I used the "macro recorder" to make this part. The whole macro, launch from a specific workbook (let's call it the *main file*), does the following things :

1. ask for a folder
2. for each file in the folder, open the file
3. select a given worksheet
4. set filters (see below)
5. save some of the data into the *main file*

Once I'm in the workbook that just has been opened, that's what I want to do

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFileName)
wb.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("abcdfg").Select

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1")
    .SlicerItems("item1").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("item2").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("item3").Selected = False
End With

'With AcvtiveSheet.PivotTables("my_table_name") EDIT : deleted, see comments
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("my_table_name")
    .PivotFields("name1").CurrentPage = "value1"
    .PivotFields("name2").CurrentPage = "value2"
    .PivotFields("name3").CurrentPage = "value3"
End With
```

The first part with the SlicerCaches works well. But I can't go through the second part. I got an error 424 "object required"  However, it works, **not always**, when I launch this part from a module in the workbook that contains the table (not the *main file*).

Have you got any idea to solve this?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `AcvtiveSheet` -> `ActiveSheet`. Get in the habit of _Always_ placing `Option Explicit` at the very top of any module: this will force you to explicitly declare all your variables but this little effort will get you much more control over your code and save you hours in mispellings seekings

Comment: Hi. I do not understand your answer. I often do `Option Explicit` but I don't see how it will help me fix this. 
Thanks for your ((very quick) answer

Comment: read my answer form the very beginning

Comment: Ok, that was a typo, but it is only here, not in my code (I can't do a proper copy/paste for many reason, so I wrote this question for scratch)

Comment: what line is throwing _"424 "object required"_ error?

Comment: `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("my_table_name")` so on of the 3 lines below

Comment: how can it be? After first error you can't go on!

Comment: I meant that the error occur on the first line, but if I delete it, it will occur on the second and so on. Therefore the issue is not on a specific line.

Comment: The issue _always_ starts on a specific line. And if you remove a house foundations no wonder if the house will fall down. Try placing a pointbreak at `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("my_table_name")` and once the code stops there use immediate window to query `?ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count`

Comment: ok, I probably use the wrong words (I'm not a native speaker). What I meant was that all of these lines causes error, but of course it appears on the first one.
But it doesn't really matter here.

Comment: have you tried the pointberak thing?